# MySQL column in view as function of aggregated columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

Is it possible to make a column in a view who's value is a function (a custom defined function) of an aggregated column? For example:

```
CREATE VIEW a_view AS SELECT
    AVG(`a`) as avg_a,
    AVG(`b`) as avg_b
    GROUP BY `c`
    FROM `A_TABLE`
```

could I add a column who's value is foo(a,b)?

Answer (score 1):

> could I add a column who's value is foo(a,b)?

Yes you can. View's are nothing but stored query and so when you say `select * from a_view` it in-turn going to run/execute the defined `SELECT` statement and will produce the result. So, if you can use a `UDF` in a select statement then the same can be used as view definition as well.